# Get all child which has child and parent_id in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to get all "posts" which has parent "blog" with id: 25 and only those "posts" which has at least one child "comment"

I am new to elasticsearch. Using version 5.

So far I know that I can use [parent_id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-parent-id-query.html), [has_child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) and [has_parent](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-has-parent-query.html)

Not sure how can I combine those queries...

so far I have:

```
GET /blog/post/_search
{
    "query": {
        "parent_id" : {
            "type" : "post",
            "id" : "25"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine queries using [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).
So, assuming you have created your mappings and data similar to this example:

```
PUT /blog 
{
  "mappings": {
    "blog": {},
    "post": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "blog" 
      }
    },
    "comment": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "post" 
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /blog/blog/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": "21" }}
{ "name": "blog 11"}
{ "index": { "_id": "25" }}
{ "name": "blog 25" }
{ "index": { "_id": "22" }}
{ "name": "blog 24"}

POST /blog/post/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": "1", "parent": "21" }}
{ "name": "post of blog 21 (with comments)"}
{ "index": { "_id": "2", "parent": "25" }}
{ "name": "post of blog 25 (with comments)"}
{ "index": { "_id": "3", "parent": "25" }}
{ "name": "post of blog 25 (without comments)"}

POST /blog/comment/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": "10", "parent": "1", "routing": "21"}}
{ "name": "comment for post 1"}
{ "index": { "_id": "11", "parent": "2", "routing": "25" }}
{ "name": "comment for post 2"}
```

Your query is:

```
GET blog/post/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "parent_id": {
            "type": "post",
            "id": "25"
          }
        },
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "comment",
            "query": {
              "match_all": {

              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe it would be more suitable to store your comments as a `nested` type in posts.
You can read more about the difference between `nested` and `parent/child` relations [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html).